# How to remove registration information of VS 2010 from a computer without reinstall Windows

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010

I want to remove visual studio 2010 from a computer i am selling but even after uninstall, it looks like my product key is still around - if you re-install it it will use the product key...

How do I remove that registration info from the computer as I don't want the new owner of the computer to use my product key. And I don't want to have to uninstall Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search the registry and delete *everything* that refers to Visual Studio and you should clobber the stored key amongst other things.

I would recommend wiping the drive (just zeroing it would probably suffice, a full secure wipe if feeling unnecessarily paranoid) and reinstalling anyway though - who knows what data you might accidentally leave lying around (or easily undeleted) otherwise, like usernames and passwords to online accounts you care about or if you have ever stored banking details on there (your buyer may not abuse any such information if found, but if they get infected by malware that goes searching for such data your accounts could be compromised).

Comment: From the question on Stackoverflow there was a comment to use Revo -= Im trying this and will then, if do not work - try this - I was not think on the points you raised, thank you.

Comment: On the end I had to do what you told me...