# How to remove registration information of VS 2010 from a computer without reinstall Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove registration information of VS 2010 from a computer without reinstall Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/145714/how-to-remove-registration-information-of-vs-2010-from-a-computer-without-reinsta)

I want to remove visual studio 2010 from a computer i am selling but even after uninstall, it looks like my product key is still around - if you re-install it it will use the product key...
How do I remove that registration info from the computer as I don't want the new owner of the computer to use my product key.
And I don't want to have to uninstall Windows.

Comment: I use the free Revo Uninstaller.  It does a great job of hunting down "left overs" when programs don't completely uninstall themselves.  Suggest you search for Revo on download.com or similar trusted site.  Not sure if it will help with VS 2010, but generally does a great job.

Comment: Hi Eric. I will give it a try right now. Thanks

Comment: Dupe http://superuser.com/questions/145714/how-to-remove-registration-information-of-vs-2010-from-a-computer-without-reinsta